# Using Gradle Sonarqube with libraries outside the project directory

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Versions:

- Sonarqube Gradle plugin - 2.2
- Sonarqube - 4.5.6
- Java Plugin Version - 3.12

We are using the [Gradle Sonarqube](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle) and we are receiving the following error (for a project in `/path/to/home/my-project`:

```
:sonarqube FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> No files nor directories matching '[/path/to/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/some-library/1.0/690113756f9fed1909ba59b6cc35bd54f68fa820/some-library-1.0.jar' in directory /path/to/home/my-project
```

These libraries are part of the Gradle `project.sourceSets.main.compileClasspath` source set. How can we make Sonarqube accept this kind of classpath? It seems the Gradle Sonarqube plugin expects that everything must be under the actual project directory.

And finally the full stack trace:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
> No files nor directories matching '[/path/to/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/some-library/1.0/7a885b1624285ea1a7b91fbd31040554a6385a10/some-library-1.0.jar' in directory /path/to/home/my-project

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No files nor directories matching '[/path/to/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/some-library/1.0/7a885b1624285ea1a7b91fbd31040554a6385a10/some-library-1.0.jar' in directory /path/to/home/my-project
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.validateDirectories(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:302)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.defineProject(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:131)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorBuilder.execute(ProjectReactorBuilder.java:114)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.projectBootstrap(ProjectScanContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:98)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.executeOldVersion(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.executeOldVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:238)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask.run(SonarQubeTask.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:623)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:606)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 14 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 3.577 secs
```

Comment: I can replicate this with the [Java Gradle example](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/java/gradle/java-gradle-simple) project where it fails complaining about `rt.jar` which runs contrary to what [the docs say](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-AdditionaldefaultsforJavaprojects) - "filtering to only include files; rt.jar and jfxrt.jar added if necessary"

Comment: What is your version of SonarQube and what is your version of the SonarQube Java analyzer?

Comment: Ah, that's important info I neglected to provide. I have edited my above answer with that info. Is the "Java analyzer" the same thing as the Gradle plugin?

Comment: Nope, Java analyzer is a SonarQube plugin installed on the SonarQube server. See its home page: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin You can get the version from http://<your SQ server>/api/plugins/installed

Comment: Thanks, I've added it in the info above.

Comment: Last needed info, please provide the full stacktrace using --stacktrace (also using --debug may help)

Comment: I've added the stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked first, but is the file `/path/to/home/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.example/some-library/1.0/7a885b1624285ea1a7b91fbd31040554a6385a10/some-library-1.0.jar` exists?

Comment: Yes, that file exists.